# How to implement SVM for a Web Prediciton Program

Tags: python, c++, machine-learning

I am building a WPP using Modified Markov Model but i need to build an SVM with a classifier to train the data of the webpages.
Whats the easiest way to implement?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/svm.html)

Example:

```
from sklearn import svm
X = [[0, 0], [1, 1]]
y = [0, 1]
clf = svm.SVC
clf.fit(X, y)
```

And then for a prediction:

```
clf.predict([[2., 2.]])
```